# How to change the maximum,minimum and major unit value of a bar chart with phpExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to create a bar chart with phpExcel.How to change the maximum and minimum values in axis options with phpExcel?And I want to create the start point of the bar with maximum value.How to do?And, how to change the major unit and minor unit with phpExcel?

Comment: Related to and it has this answer which seems to have helped others https://stackoverflow.com/a/36378038/8958173